# Is there a way to launch a terminal window (or cmd on Windows) and pass/run a command?

Tags: node.js, electron

### Question

Is it possible to do the following?

- open a new `cmd.exe` or `terminal` (on MacOS / Linux) window
- pass / run a command, e.g. `cd <path>`

### Problem

I can open cmd by running this command:

```
"$electron.shell.openItem('cmd.exe')"
```

But `shell.openItem` doesn't allow to pass the arguments / commands.

---

I tried using `child_process` but I couldn't make it work at all, it doesn't open a new terminal window:

```
const { spawn, exec } = require('child_process');
spawn('C:/Windows/System32/cmd.exe');
```

I also tried running the following command, but still nothing:

```
spawn( 'cmd.exe', [ '/c', 'echo ASDASD' ], { stdio: [0, 1, 2] } )
```

---

The only possible solution that I see is to create a `command.bat`:

`start cmd.exe /K "cd /D C:\test"`

And then use `openItem`:

```
"$electron.shell.openItem('command.bat')"
```

But that would only work on Windows

Comment: @pergy I read it, but as I mentioned, I couldn't make it to open a new `cmd.exe` / `terminal` window and pass an argument. How do I do that?

Comment: yes, I noticed, my bad. I thought it's only about arguments

Comment: Is the terminal important?  Because you can use the various functions within `child_process` to run commands anyway, so unless you need specific environment of a shell, then you can execute any binary otherwise

Comment: Seems to me that you don't see `cmd.exe` popping bc you don't pipe stdio. Try this `spawn(
  'cmd.exe',
  [
    '/c',
    'echo ASD'
  ], {
    stdio: [0, 1, 2]
  }
)`
It doesn't open the console in new window though.

Comment: @OwenC.Jones I'm trying to implement the "open in terminal" functionality so that users could open selected path in terminal. But can I execute a command within `child_process` that would run `C\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe` and launch the `cmd.exe` window?

Comment: @pergy hmm, thanks for the command, but still nothing. I can see the `childProcess` object if I console.log your command, but it still doesn't open a new window

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a working example showing how to open a Terminal window at a specific path (~/Desktop for instance) on `macOS`, from a renderer script:

```
const { app } = require ('electron').remote;
const atPath = app.getPath ('desktop');
const { spawn } = require ('child_process');
let openTerminalAtPath = spawn ('open', [ '-a', 'Terminal', atPath ]);
openTerminalAtPath.on ('error', (err) => { console.log (err); });
```

It should be easy to adapt it to any selected atPath...
As for running other commands, I haven't found a way yet...

And here is the equivalent working code for `Linux Mint Cinnamon` or `Ubuntu`:

```
const { app } = require ('electron').remote;
const terminal = 'gnome-terminal';
const atPath = app.getPath ('desktop');
const { spawn } = require ('child_process');
let openTerminalAtPath = spawn (terminal, { cwd: atPath });
openTerminalAtPath.on ('error', (err) => { console.log (err); });
```

Please note that the name of the terminal application may be different, depending on the Linux flavor (for instance `'mate-terminal'` on `Linux Mint MATE`), and also that the full path to the application can be explicitly defined, to be on the safe side:

```
const terminal = '/usr/bin/gnome-terminal';
```

HTH...

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I found the solution how to do it on Windows as well! Thank you!

Comment: `open -a Terminal` is not opening a new Terminal window. It seems that if Terminal is already open it does nothing. Using `open -a Terminal --new` opens a completely new Terminal instance (and restores all previously open windows) which is not what I want. Basically I want to open a new terminal window tab.

Answer (score 14):

### Solution

I finally found a way to do it on Windows:

```
var child_process = require('child_process');
child_process.exec("start cmd.exe /K cd /D C:/test");
```

---

### Notes

- You have to add the word `start` to open a new command window
- Instead of `cd /D C:/test` you can specify any other command, e.g. `python`
- `/D` is to make sure it will change the current drive automatically, depending on the path specified
- `/K` removes the initial message
- Don't use `execSync` it will lock the app until the terminal (command
  prompt) window is closed

As for MacOS, looks like it's possible to do with `osascript`

`osascript -e 'tell application "Terminal" to activate' -e 'tell application "System Events" to tell process "Terminal" to keystroke "t" using command down'`

Comment: This works but it does not die when the parent process does - it keeps running. I need it to exit with the parent.

Comment: In MacOS Mojave that `osascript` command triggers a warning that "this app wants to control your computer". Accepting the warning still fails the command. It seems you have to manually open Security settings and set the app to allow control.